# How to cover statements inside a loop in test coeverage

Tags: javascript, tdd, hapi.js

I have a function, code is written below. I am using lab as code coverage tool.

```
getClients = async (partnerId) => {
    try {
      const results = await PartnersClients.findAll({
        attributes: ['clientId'],
        where: {
          partnerId,
        },
        include: [{
          model: Models.Entries,
          attributes: ['section'],
        }],
      });
      if (!results.length) return false;
      return results.map(result => ({
        clientId: result.dataValues.clientId,
        section: result.dataValues.Entries.length ? result.dataValues.Entries[0].dataValues.section : '',
      }));
    } catch (error) {
      return false;
    }
  };
```

I have written tests for it but this line `section: result.dataValues.Entries.length ? result.dataValues.Entries[0].dataValues.section : ''` shown as not covered. Also on most of the code lines where I have used loops or iterator methods are showing as not covered. I am wondering how should I cover it. als

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's kind of odd, I have quite a lot of loops like that and it lab test-report says they are covered.

Here is my code

```
handler: async (request, h) => {
    try {        
        const results = await Content.find(contentFilters).sort({createdAt: -1})        
            .exec();
        const {simpleResults} = request.query;
        const contentList = results.results.map(row => simpleResults ? row.simpleApiData() : row.apiData());        
        return {
            status: true,
            results: contentList,
        }
    } catch (e) {
        /* $lab:coverage:off$ */
        request.server.log(['error', 'content', 'list'], e);

        return Boom.badRequest(e.message, e);
        /* $lab:coverage:on$ */
    }
}
```

and here is the test code that covers all the lines.

```
it('It should list contents', async () => {
    const res = await server.inject({
        url: `/content?${key}=${filters[key]}&page=1`, // I also have another test with additional "simpleResults" parameter added to this url, query parameters validated by Joi ofc. simpleResults: Joi.boolean(),
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": token
        }
    });

    expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
    expect(res.result.status).to.equal(true);
    expect(res.result.results).to.be.an.array();
    expect(res.result.results).to.have.length(1);
    expect(res.result.results[0].title).to.equal('Game Of Thrones');
});
```

I have many other complex loops in my code and most of them covered with test. Is is possible to show us your test code, how do you test your conditions?